# Adding . in string whenever it changes from character to number, or number to character in python

Tags: python, regex

I have a bunch of strings that look like this:
7EE1,
4NF1,
5NF4a,
8F1

They all start with a number, following a few characters, and then another number, then another few characters. And there is no limit on how many chucks they can go. There is no limit for consecutive characters. What I am trying to do is adding "." into the string whenever it changes from character to number or vice verse.  For example, the desired output is:
7.EE.1,
4.NF.1,
5.NF.4.a,
8.F.1

I think it can be solved with regular expression, but I haven't learned it before. I am working on creating a regex for this. Any tips would be appreciated!

Comment: Where have you gotten so far with your pattern or your Python code? Where *specifically* in that attempt are you getting stuck? Share a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to illustrate what issue you're having, in accordance with [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 3):

Here is a very compact way of doing this using regular expressions:

```py
inp = ["7EE1", "4NF1", "5NF4a", "8F1"];
output = [re.sub(r'(\d+(?=\D)|\D+(?=\d))', r'\1.', x) for x in inp]
print(output)  # ['7.EE.1', '4.NF.1', '5.NF.4.a', '8.F.1']
```

The regex works by matching (and capturing) a series of either all digit characters, or all non digit characters, which in turn is followed by a character of the opposite class.  It then replaces with whatever was capture followed by a dot separator.  Here is an explanation:

```
(           match AND capture:
    \d+     one or more digits
    (?=\D)  followed by a non digit character
    |       OR
    \D+     one or more non digits
    (?=\d)  followed by a digit character
)           stop capture
```

Note that the lookaheads used above are zero width, so nothing is captured from them.

Comment: This is very clean with great explanation!

Comment: Thanks a lot! You explained very nicely! A follow-up question: does '\1.' means whatever got matched previously?

Comment: Yes, `\1` is the first capture group, which in this case would be the single character preceding a dot separator.

Answer (score 2):

One way without using `re`:

```
from itertools import groupby

inp = ["7EE1", "4NF1", "5NF4a", "8F1"]

def add_dot(string):
    return ".".join(["".join(g) 
                     for k, g in groupby(string, key=str.isdigit)])

[add_dot(i) for i in inp]
```

Output:

```
['7.EE.1', '4.NF.1', '5.NF.4.a', '8.F.1']
```